# Angular directive to set background color of a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say I have a div element:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   some text
</div>
```

How do I write an angular directive such that the background depends on my input?

For example I tried:

```
<div id="wrapper" color temperature="51">
   some text
</div>
```

with directive:

```
.directive('color', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      temperature: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-class="temperatureCSS">Test</div>',
    link: function($scope) {

      $scope.$watch('temperature', function(v) {
        if(!v) { return; }

        var temperature = v;
        console.log("temperature", v)

        if(temperature > 31) {
          $scope.temperatureCSS = "redCSS" // redCSS works and is defined
        }

      });
    }
  }
})
```

But that does not exactly work. I think the issue is somewhere in the template.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the angular [documentation on directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  It looks like part of your problem is that you're trying to insert a template using an attribute directive.  If you want to insert a template you need to specify an element directive.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-restrictions) might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Please could you explain more about the issue you're facing. Because what I understand from the code you provided above is let's say you have an input field, and whenever you change the value in that field the background should change based on the condition in the **$watch** function.

So, if that is the case, let's assume we have controller with code like below:

```
.controller('Main', function($scope){

  $scope.myInputValue = 20;

})
```

and input field bounded to the scope property **myInputValue** using ngModel directive like below:

```
<input ng-model="myInputValue" />
```

now what you want to do is just using the property in your directive

```
<div id="wrapper" color temperature="myInputValue">
  some text
</div>
```

and that's it.